# Pila a un fichero en C

Tags: c, archivo, pilas

He pensado pasar los datos de una pila a un fichero binario, tengo hecho unos pasos pero creo que están mal, me visualiza el ultimo elemento elemento introducido, osea el primero de la pila.

Código:

```
typedef struct nodo
{
    int dato;
    struct nodo *siguiente;
}Nodo;

Nodo *principioPila = NULL;

//Prototipos de funciones
void escribirFichero(void);
int introducirDatos(void);
void leerFichero(void);

int main()
{
    printf("PILA A UN FICHERO BINARIO\n\n");
    escribirFichero();
    system("CLS");
    printf("DATOS DE LA PILA GUARDADOS EN EL FICHERO\n\n");
    printf("NUMEROS\n");
    leerFichero();

    return 0;
}

void escribirFichero(void)
{
    FILE *fichero = fopen("pila.dat","wb");

    if(fichero == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error en el fichero");
    }
    else
    {   
        Nodo *nuevo;
        int numero = introducirDatos();

        while(numero!=0)
        {
            nuevo = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
            nuevo->dato = numero;
            nuevo->siguiente = principioPila;
            principioPila = nuevo;
            numero = introducirDatos();
        }
        fwrite(&principioPila,sizeof(principioPila),1,fichero);     
    }
    fclose(fichero);
}

int introducirDatos(void)
{
    int x;
    printf("Dato: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    return x;
}

void leerFichero(void)
{
    FILE *fichero = fopen("pila.dat","rb");

    if(fichero == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error en el fichero");
    }
    else
    {
        fread(&principioPila,sizeof(principioPila),1,fichero);
        while(!feof(fichero))
        {
            printf(" %d",principioPila->dato);
            principioPila = principioPila->siguiente;
            fread(&principioPila,sizeof(principioPila),1,fichero);  
        }   
    }
    fclose(fichero);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El programa funciona de chiripa. Si hicieses dos programas independientes, uno para escribir el fichero y otro para leerlo no funcionaría jamás.

Empecemos:

```
while(numero!=0)
{
    nuevo = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    nuevo->dato = numero;
    nuevo->siguiente = principioPila;
    principioPila = nuevo;
    numero = introducirDatos();
}
fwrite(&principioPila,sizeof(principioPila),1,fichero);
```

Este fragmento tiene dos errores importantes:

1. Solo guardas un registro, independientemente del número de elementos en la pila (esto imposibilita que puedas recuperar más de un valor)
2. En el fichero está guardando direcciones de memoria, no el valor de los elementos.

Vayamos por partes:

**Solo guardas un registro**

Efectivamente, tu algoritmo únicamente tiene un `fwrite` y además está fuera de cualquier bucle, luego dificilmente vas a poder volcar toda la pila en el fichero.

Necesitas iterar sobre la pila para poder guardar todos los datos:

```
Nodo* ptr = principioPila;
while( ptr )
{
  fwrite(/* ... */); // Lo vemos más adelante
  ptr = ptr->siguiente;
}
```

**Guardas direcciones de memoria**

Con `&principioPila` vas a recuperar la dirección de memoria donde se ubica el puntero... y eso es lo que estás almacenando en el fichero. Tu necesitas almacenar el valor del nodo en cuestión. El programa está funcionando porque, al no liberar memoria, las direcciones de memoria son válidas entre la escritura  la lectura.

La instrucción de escritura debería lucir así:

```
fwrite(&(principioPila->dato),sizeof(int),1,fichero);
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^
//               (1)              (2)
```

Y la explicación es la siguiente:

1. El único dato que tiene sentido en cada nodo es el campo `dato`. El otro valor que se almacena en el nodo es una dirección de memoria... y este dato cambiará entre ejecuciones, luego no tiene sentido almacenarlo.
2. Como solo vas a almacenar un entero tienes que garantizar que el programa solo escribe el número de bytes ocupado por un entero.

**para rematar la escritura**

Con los cambios anteriores ya has guardado la pila en el fichero... el siguiente paso debería ser liberar la memoria de la pila. Este paso te lo dejo a ti ya que ni tan siquiera lo has intentado tocar.

... y ahora vamos a repasar la lectura:

```
fread(&principioPila,sizeof(principioPila),1,fichero);
while(!feof(fichero))
{
    printf(" %d",principioPila->dato);
    principioPila = principioPila->siguiente;
    fread(&principioPila,sizeof(principioPila),1,fichero);  
}
```

A diferencia de la escritura, aquí si tienes un `fread` dentro del bucle, luego en principio el programa va a ser capaz de leer varios registros... pero estás intentando recuperar direcciones de memoria... mal asunto.

De acuerdo a lo que hemos visto en la escritura, la lectura debería ser así:

```
int dato;
fread(&dato,sizeof(int),1,fichero);

nuevo = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
nuevo->dato = dato;
nuevo->siguiente = principioPila;
// ...
```

Es decir, tienes que reconstruir la pila. Es lo esperable cuando lees un fichero... no sabes lo que te vas a encontrar en el mismo, luego tienes que ir reconstruyendo tus listas sobre la marcha.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo! Perfecta explicación.